# Azure AppService Convert word to PDF

Tags: c#, azure, pdf, ms-word, azure-web-app-service

Is there any way to convert a Word document to a PDF in an Azure App Service?  I can't use any Office libraries as I don't want any office dependencies.   A lot of the third party solutions seem to use GDI+ which is not a possibility on Azure App Service.

My only solution looks like moving to an Azure Cloud Service which does have GDI+, however I would prefer to keep my app as an App Service.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/products/words/net) has a solution for this, and since it is platform independent I am gonna go ahead and guess it has no problematic dependencies.
The problem is that it costs money.

As for a free solution you can call a third party web service, there are many of them, I guess some of them have some REST APi.

I would suggest to  take a look at [OpenXML](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) it is an office document library, and I am pretty sure it has no weird dependencies The problem is that it does not support conversions, so you will either have to do it manually, or search the web for some third party library that helps you do it, I couldn't find any...

Comment: I had seen Aspose, I was hoping to find a cheaper method. If not I may just have to use Aspose